# How the DHCP option set affect the EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am using `AWS`.

I have `VPC` which uses the `DHCP option set` such as  `128.1.100.xxx`,`128.1.100.xxx`,`AmazonProvidedDNS`

In this environment, systems using `privateDNS` such as `VPC Endpoint` does not work in `EC2`.

If there are not two servers , there is only `AmazonProvidedDNS` it works.

So, I wonder how to be determind which one should be used?